# Tring to install Atom Text Editor on my Arch by using Yaourt

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, package-management, editors, yaourt

I am currently trying to install [Atom Text Editor](https://atom.io/) (*atom-editor* on **Yaourt**). However I get the errors below:

```
==> Downloading atom-editor-arch PKGBUILD from AUR...
x .SRCINFO
x .gitignore
x PKGBUILD
x README.md
x about-arch.patch
x atom
x atom-arch.install
x atom.desktop
x theme.patch
atom-editor-arch 1.8.0.arch0.2.1-2  (2016-06-07 15:07)
( Unsupported package: Potentially dangerous ! )
==> Edit PKGBUILD ? [Y/n] ("A" to abort)
==> ------------------------------------
==> n

==> atom-editor-arch dependencies:
 - alsa-lib (already installed)
 - desktop-file-utils (already installed)
 - gconf (already installed)
 - gtk2 (already installed)
 - libgnome-keyring (already installed)
 - libnotify (already installed)
 - libxtst (already installed)
 - nodejs (already installed)
 - nss (already installed)
 - python2 (already installed)
 - git (already installed) [makedepend]
 - npm (already installed) [makedepend]
 - namcap (package found)
 - pkgbuild-introspection (package found)


==> Edit atom-arch.install ? [Y/n] ("A" to abort)
==> ---------------------------------------------
==> n

==> Continue building atom-editor-arch ? [Y/n]
==> ------------------------------------------
==> y

==> Building and installing package
==> Install or build missing dependencies for atom-editor-arch:
[sudo] password for shazam: 
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (4) pyalpm-0.8-1  python-pyelftools-0.23-3  namcap-3.2.7-1  pkgbuild-introspection-8-1

Total Download Size:   0.28 MiB
Total Installed Size:  1.70 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
:: Retrieving packages...
 pyalpm-0.8-1-x86_64                                                                  42.4 KiB   109K/s 00:00 [##################################################################] 100%
 python-pyelftools-0.23-3-any                                                        155.1 KiB   391K/s 00:00 [##################################################################] 100%
 namcap-3.2.7-1-any                                                                   84.1 KiB  0.00B/s 00:00 [##################################################################] 100%
 pkgbuild-introspection-8-1-any                                                        4.4 KiB  0.00B/s 00:00 [##################################################################] 100%
(4/4) checking keys in keyring                                                                                [##################################################################] 100%
(4/4) checking package integrity                                                                              [##################################################################] 100%
(4/4) loading package files                                                                                   [##################################################################] 100%
(4/4) checking for file conflicts                                                                             [##################################################################] 100%
(4/4) checking available disk space                                                                           [##################################################################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/4) installing pyalpm                                                                                       [##################################################################] 100%
(2/4) installing python-pyelftools                                                                            [##################################################################] 100%
(3/4) installing namcap                                                                                       [##################################################################] 100%
(4/4) installing pkgbuild-introspection                                                                       [##################################################################] 100%
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/1) Updating manpage index...
==> Making package: atom-editor-arch 1.8.0.arch0.2.1-2 (Wed Jun  8 20:16:49 IST 2016)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving sources...
  -> Downloading atom-1.8.0.tar.gz...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   117    0   117    0     0     87      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--    87
100  9.8M  100  9.8M    0     0  1236k      0  0:00:08  0:00:08 --:--:-- 2309k
  -> Downloading about-arch-1.5.18.tar.gz...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   124    0   124    0     0     99      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--    99
100 30559    0 30559    0     0  10790      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:-- 23911
  -> Found atom
  -> Found atom.desktop
  -> Found theme.patch
  -> Found about-arch.patch
==> Validating source files with md5sums...
    atom-1.8.0.tar.gz ... Passed
    about-arch-1.5.18.tar.gz ... FAILED
    atom ... Passed
    atom.desktop ... Passed
    theme.patch ... Passed
    about-arch.patch ... Passed
==> ERROR: One or more files did not pass the validity check!
==> ERROR: Makepkg was unable to build atom-editor-arch.
==> Restart building atom-editor-arch ? [y/N]
==> -----------------------------------------
==> N
```

What exactly is going wrong here? Why are my patches not passing the md5sums checks? Is it something to do with my proxy? I have set my *all_proxy* environment variable to be my corporate proxy. Is there any way in which I can use the .deb or .rpm files to install this program onto my computer?

Comment: Should I seperate this out into two questions?

Comment: @JigglyNaga Done, please delete your comments that refer to the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to the [package AUR page](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/atom-editor-arch/) and [View Changes](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/log/?h=atom-editor-arch), you can see that in [the most recent commit](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/commit/?h=atom-editor-arch&id=db7dff6f7f6e69ef25f293a5116921fddda9de31) one of the version numbers was increased, but that file's corresponding md5sum didn't change.

```
 # Module Versions
 _about_arch_url="fusion809/about"
-_about_arch_ver=1.5.17
+_about_arch_ver=1.5.18
 _dark_bint_syntax_ver=0.8.6
 _fusion_ui_ver=0.10.5
 _language_archlinux_ver=0.2.1
```

So that's why the md5sums no longer match.

If you have the time, the responsible thing to do, to fix the problem for you and others, would be to report the problem to the AUR package maintainer.  From 
https://aur.archlinux.org/ :

> To report packaging bugs contact the package maintainer or leave a comment on the appropriate package page.

The quickest fix, just to make it build, would be for you to take the "Edit PKGBUILD ? [Y/n]" option, and do either (but only ONE) of

- Change `_about_arch_ver` back to `1.5.17`
- Update the relevant (in this case, second) line in `md5sums=(`
  [Download the new version](https://github.com/fusion809/about/releases), confirm (through any means that fits your security policy) that you trust it, run `md5sum` on it to see the new checksum

Comment: I definitely would like to report it, but I'm not sure as to how to go about it.

Comment: let me also try and change the arch version and get back to you.

Comment: Changing the arch version does not seem to work. It is just stuck at *installing build modules*

Comment: @SharanDuggirala - then try the second solution suggested by JigglyNaga:  change the `md5sum` in `PKGBUILD`

Comment: @SharanDuggirala How long did you leave it to run?  I tried with `1.5.17`, and `makepkg` took 13mins.  Bug-report instructions added to my answer.

Comment: @grochmal What should I even change the `md5sums` to? I am sure I can trust this file.

Comment: @JigglyNaga I was running it for a while (at least 2 hours), to no avail. Let me try that again. The `md5sums` definitely pass through when I change the `PKGBUILD`

Comment: @SharanDuggirala It's the output of `md5sum <filename>` - see http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/198/md5-checksum-how-to/

Comment: @JigglyNaga Hey, so changing the version, seems to have worked, but is spitting out new errors.

Comment: @JigglyNaga Let me add these errors to the question.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala - yep, correct, if `makepkg` starts without any clever disables (i.e. `--skipinteg`) you should have the correct file.

Comment: @JigglyNaga If you could elaborate on how to change the `md5sums` values, so that it goes through verification, I can accept this answer as a total solution and make a report to the AUR Package maintainer.